# How to use my global Application class method inside a thread

Tags: java, android

I've created a class that extends Application.
This class starts a service when the application is loaded.
This service is running a thread in a loop, and need to update the application global variable throw the getter\setter method in this class:

```
public class AppLoader extends Application {
    private boolean isInternetOn, isGpsOn, isThereActivityRunning;
    private String results;

    public String getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(String results)  { }

    public boolean getIsInternetOn() {
        return isInternetOn;
    } 

    public void setIsInternetOn(boolean state) {
        this.isInternetOn = state;  
    }

    public boolean getIsGpsOn() {
        return isGpsOn;
    }

    public void setIsGpsOn(boolean state) {
        this.isGpsOn = state;   
    }

    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, this, ServerConnection.class);
       startService(intent);
       Log.d("ServiceStart", "ServerConnection.java Service has been started");
    }
}
```

I want to use the getter setter methods inside the thread and I couldn't understand how to do it.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a Handler that you can send messages to.  This is a very easy way to communicate across threads.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing things very strangely.

As a rule of thumb: *don't* use an Application class unless you understand the framework very well, and know exactly what you're doing and why you need to be doing it.

Instead of starting your service in your Application class, you should be starting it in one of you Activities.  Along with that, as @CaseyB points out, you should be using some other mechanism to communicate back and forth between your Service and the rest of your app.  Instead of touching variables, you can pass Messages, implement an AIDL interface, etc...

Comment: i actually did it before.
i've sent message back an forth but this service needs to run as soon as the application loads, and stop when it stops..
i need the results of this service to be available for all my activities and not just one specific..
i will be really greatfull if you could help me with using the application methods in a thread..

Comment: Just because you've done it before doesn't mean you should.  This is a bad way to design things.  The application never *stops* anyway.  Put this in your main Activity, otherwise this is a horribly broken design...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you specify your own customized Application implementation in AndroidManifest.xml properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... ...>
  <application android:name="com.example.AppLoader" ... ...>
... ...
```

If you are within a android.content.Context (Activity, Service and etc.), simply get/cast an instance of your customized android.app.Application then call whatever your implement as public method on this object:

```
boolean gpsOn = ((AppLoader) getApplication()).getIsGpsOn();
... ...
((AppLoader) getApplication()).setIsGpsOn("true");
```

If you are calling setter in thread, you need implement synchronized block properly.